# Cannot use .place for a label frame in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I've been working on adding label frames to my window but for some reason whenever I use .place it never places the frame. Grid and pack work though. I'm trying to get the label frame right in the middle of the screen through coordinates. Heres my code (the error is somewhere in the createstock functiom):

```
import tkinter as tk
import yfinance

class StockWindow:
    def __init__(self,master,number):

        self.master = master
        self.frame=tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()
        w, h = master.winfo_screenwidth(), master.winfo_screenheight()
        self.master.overrideredirect(1)
        self.master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
        self.master.focus_set() # <-- move focus to this widget
        self.master.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: e.widget.quit())
        #################################################
        ## Labels
        self.amountChanged = tk.Label(self.master,text = "$1000")
        self.amountChanged.place(x=w/2,y=h/2)
        self.highestChangedStock = tk.Label(self.master,text = "Amzn")
        self.highestChangedStock.place(x=w/2+10,y=h/2+40)
        self.lowestChangedStock = tk.Label(self.master,text = "this one")
        self.stockTips = tk.Label(self.master,text = "Buy some")
        self.stockTips.place(x=2,y=777)
        self.marketChange = tk.Label(self.master,text = "Alot!")
        self.marketChange.place(x=23,y=66)
        self.stockNews = tk.Label(self.master,text = "News Here!")
        self.stockNews.place(x=23,y=234)
        self.stockNewds = tk.Label(self.master,text = "News Hewewere!")
        self.stockNewds.place(x=300,y=300)
        ## Buttons
        self.seeAllStocks = tk.Button(self.master,text ="do you wanna see more stocks?")
        self.seeAllStocks.place(x=0,y=0)
        self.goBack =tk.Button(self.master,text = "Go back",command=self.close_windows)
        self.goBack.place(x=100,y=100)
        self.createStock("afdhsfdhsfhsfghsgfhsdg",3,30)
        #########
    def createStock(self,name,pricechange,placement):
        stockframe = tk.LabelFrame(self.frame,text='')
        #stockframe.size(200)
        stockframe.place(x=400,y=400,height=10,width=10) 
        #stockframe.pack(expand='yes',fill='both')
        #stockframe.grid(column=5,row=5)
        tempLabel = tk.Label(stockframe,text=name)

        tempLabel.pack()
    def close_windows(self):
        self.master.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `self.frame` is used as the parent of the label frame, but it has a height of 1x1 since there's nothing in it. Thus, any widget placed inside it will also be invisible.

If you want to use `place` to center a widget, the simplest solution is to use relative coordinates with a relative x and y coordinate of .5 (ie: 50% of the width and height of the window).

For example, you don't need to place the labelframe inside a label inside the root window. Just remove `self.frame` and use relative coordinates for the label frame:

```
    stockframe = tk.LabelFrame(self.master,text='')
    stockframe.place(relx=.5, rely=.5)
```